# Columnstore Index and Nonclustered Index on table

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, sqlperformance, non-clustered-index, columnstore

We have a table definition below with a columnstore index and nonclustered row indices. The data in this table increases 10K per day and in a year can have 400K ColNumber with each having 1 to many ColProperty. This table will be used mostly for reads/reference and hardly have updates. Would it be beneficial to have the nonclustered row indices as well or just the columnstore index would be sufficient?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SimpleTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ColNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ColProperty] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ColValue] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ColDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCIX_SimpleTable ON [dbo].[SimpleTable];

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_SimpleTable_NumberProperty ON [dbo].[SimpleTable] (ColNumber,ColProperty);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SimpleTable_Id ON [dbo].[SimpleTable] (Id);
```

Comment: For which queries? A columnstore index accelerates aggregate operations while a non-clustered index on top of it accelerates point searches. Nonclustered indexes are required to specify primary keys, unique constraints etc, so they're useful for more than just accelerating queries. I'd put a UNIQUE index on `Id` no matter what

Comment: On the other hand, that schema looks like an Entity-Attribute-Value table. That's a very problematic schema no matter the indexes you use. With ColumnStores, it's far worse, as the columns become useless - instead of containing a few values of a specific type, they now contain random values with no relation at all. It's now even *more* expensive to query that table, or group by a certain "field". The solution is to simply *not* use EAV

Comment: When you have so little data, that's updates so *in*frequently, you gain no flexibility Fromm using EAV, only problems. SQL Server offers a *lot* of features for storing semi-structured data. Sparse columns allow you to create columns for all expected fields without taking up storage. You could store extra data into an XML or JSON field and use XML and JSON functions to query it.